# Java application is unable to connect to Cassandra cluster using the provided contact point

Tags: spring-boot, maven, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

The error is as the following:

```
ERROR 1912 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/oss/protocol/internal/SegmentCodec] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.oss.protocol.internal.SegmentCodec
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.DefaultDriverContext.<init>(DefaultDriverContext.java:170) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.13.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildContext(SessionBuilder.java:968) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.13.0.jar:na]
```

And code is as:

```
public List<String> getCassandraTables(String cassandraHost,String cassandraUsername,String cassandraPassword,String datacenter,String cassandraKeyspace){
      try{
            
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(cassandraHost,9042);

        DriverConfigLoader loader = DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
        .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_USER_NAME,cassandraUsername)
        .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_PASSWORD,cassandraPassword).build();

        CqlSession builder = CqlSession.builder()
        .addContactPoint(address)
        .withConfigLoader(loader)
        .withKeyspace(cassandraKeyspace)
        .withLocalDatacenter(datacenter)
        .build();

        Metadata metadata = builder.getMetadata();
        KeyspaceMetadata keyspaceMetadata = metadata.getKeyspace(cassandraKeyspace)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Keyspace not found: " + cassandraKeyspace));
        List<String> tableNames = keyspaceMetadata.getTables().values().stream()
        .map(table->table.getName().toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return tableNames;
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get tables from the Cassandra cluster: "+e.getMessage());
        return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml so we can see dependencies?

Comment: Was this line run?  I don't see it in your output: `System.out.println("Failed to get tables from the Cassandra cluster: "+e.getMessage());`

Comment: Also, possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327809/cassandra-springboot-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-datastax-oss-proto

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your post:

- what you've configured as the `cassandraHost`, and
- what the full error message + full stack trace is.

However if this is the same problem you've raised in [Unable to connect to cluster from Spring Boot app, getting ConnectionInitException: "Could not reach any contact point"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120634/), then I believe the issue is that you have specified the wrong host as `localhost` instead of the IP address that Cassandra is using to listen for client connections. You should use the same address as you've configured for `rpc_address` in `cassandra.yaml`. Cheers!